# Concurrent Async HTTP Post: Is value thread safe?

Tags: angularjs, http, asynchronous

Following is a function which may be called in concurrence. I would like to know whether `value1` and `value2` are threadsafe

```
var value1 = 0;
postSomething = function(model){
   return this.$http.post(url, model).then(function(response){
     if(model == "hello")
       value1 = true; 
     else
       value2 = true;
   }, function(response){});
}
```

Take for example:

Call with `model == hello` is made, meanwhile before the server responds another call with `model == bye` is made. What would happen in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that javascript does not use threads; Running code won't be interrupted, but asynchronous calls to external resources are not necessarily processed in the order they are called. (rather, they are usually processed in the order the answers are received)

Variables accessed outside of the scope of a function that is called, are not protected.

In this specific case; When the callback receives a model == "bye", the value2 global will be set to true from that moment on (it doesn't exist before then, please note that value2 has not been initialised like vlaue1 has). When the callback receives a model == "hello", the value1 will be set from that moment on.

If they would both be writing to the same variable, the variable would have the value that it would have gotten from the last callback-invocation that has been processed. This can indeed be unpredictable at times.

A slightly long answer to a slightly confusing question. Does this answer your question?